# install ssh public key stored on Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I have a ubuntu 18.04 server and I need to install a ssh public key. The key is stored on my windows host machine.

Comment: Unclear as to what you're asking. Can't you just scp the key over to the server or even cut and paste into a file?

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys-on-ubuntu-1804

Answer (score 0):

I assume that I need to clarify your question.

- Are you want Windows machine to remote to Linux machine?
- Are you want Linux machine to remote to Windows machine?
- Or you want to have one machine where manage all of SSH key? (If this right, you should be considering SSH Secrets Engine by HashiCorp Vault)

Firstly, SSH is an access credential in SSH protocol. You create a pair of SSH keys on local machine, includes private key ( *id_rsa* ) and public key ( *id_rsa.pub* ). Then you send your public keys to *authorized_keys* file on remote machine. After that, you can remote to remote server without password.

Generally, SSH key are cryptographic keys using a public key cryptosystem.

**How does authentication work?**
You can refer this link at [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/9366/ssh-public-private-key-pair?noredirect=1&lq=1) channel.

Back to your question:

- If you want Linux machine to remote to Windows machine, then you need
  to create SSH key pair in Linux machine, then add the public key to
  Windows Machine. ( You can install OpenSSH server on Windows. )
- If you want Windows machine to remote to Linux machine, then you need to
  create SSH key pair in Windows machine. You can use Putty tool for
  creating SSH key. Then add the public key to *~/.ssh/authorized_keys.*

**Note:**

- You need to add the public keys to authorized_keys inside *~/.ssh* in
  home directory of user who you want to under.
- Also remember to attention on SSH key size. Please refer [this paper](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-57pt1r4.pdf).